# Conversion to horizontal dropouts (for fixed gear), V-brake

Tags: fixed-gear, conversion, dropouts

If I convert vertical dropouts (as on picture) to horizontal dropouts as on youtube video by cutting and welding:

.

Will there be any challenges with the V-brakes ? If axle hole more or less will stay on same place, there shouldn't be any problem ?

[image]

Comment: Note that your example frame has very little adjustment, so aim to have that relative position in the front half of your slot.

Comment: Is the drop out replacement something you're having a professional do, or are you a skilled welder/brazee yourself?

Comment: @whatsisname, from the video above, I doesn't seems, that you need to be a high professional welder. I assume that the basic skill should be enough...

Comment: @MichaelD: there is a saying, when someone is good enough, they make it look easy. There is more than "basic skill" being exhibited in that video.

Comment: I would only describe the video as basic skill. I’m not trained in any way but have learned to use a mig welder - the dude in this video has it set up wrong, to have that much build up and spatter everywhere, so much extra material to have to grind down after welding. Needs to improve his technique.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

V-brake calipers have a radial (with respect to the wheel) adjustment range, so they can accommodate the wheel axle moving fore or aft a little.

What you need to do is make sure that the placement of the new dropouts does not place the wheel axle such that the brake track on the rim is outside the range of caliper adjustment.

You could do this with a simple cardboard template that marks the axle to brake track distance.

Answer (score 5):

The "horizontal" dropouts that are usually used with rim brakes are not completely horizontal but slanted so that adjusting chain tension moves the rim along tangent where the brake pads make contact with rim. In the video preview picture, the front-facing dropout is aligned like this. With this kind of dropouts, there is no problem with fixed gear, but with totally horizontal track-style dropouts you will have to adjust the brakes every time you adjust chain tension.